# how to use tf.print (not tf.Print) in high-level Estimator api

Tags: tensorflow

Currently, I'm using `tf.Print` to print(debug) tensor in estimator, but this api is marked deprecated, and recommend me to use tf.print instead. According to the [RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/14/files), by using tf.print, I need to have control of the running session, but `Estimator` is designed to hide session and graph from users. So, how to use `tf.print` in Estimator?

Comment: You can try `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook` to print tensor in Estimator.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `tf.print` in graph mode, that's how `tf.estimator` works, you can just use `tf.print` as a drop-in replacement for `tf.Print`, you just have to force the execution of the `tf.print` operation before the execution of a tensor in your model_fn, hence, given the input tensor, `input_` of your model_fn, you can just:

```
    print_op = tf.print(tensor_to_log)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        first_layer_output = first_inpyt_layer(input_)
```

or even

```
    print_op = tf.print(tensor_to_log)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        input_ = tf.identity(input_)
    # define your model using input_ as usual
```